# Как сделать уникальным ID у <tr>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть список `<tr>`:

### [image: Оригинал]

Мне нужно при загрузке страницы средствами **JS** сделать вот так:

[image: Как нужно сделать]

Как это можно реализовать? Я уже пробовал: нашел подобный скрипт, но он отрабатывает не так, как мне нужно:

```
var i = 0;
function test() {
    i++;
    timeR = setTimeout("test()", 100);
    document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = i;
    if (i >= 50) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, что заметили. Исправлю. Очепятка ;)

Comment: А в таком виде и не отработает. Некоторые браузеры в поиске по ID в принципе возвращают только один элемент. т.е. проставить id не проблема, но для этого нада сначала найти элементы.  А вот найти все элементы вы по $("#select") вы не сможете.

Comment: Неужели нельзя вытянуть все #select и начать отсчет?

Comment: У меня есть такой скрипт `<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;

 function test()
{
     
     i++;
     timeR=setTimeout("test()", 100);
  document.getElementById('select').innerHTML=i;
  
  if(i>=50){i=0;}
}


</script>
`

Comment: на **body** вешаю событие, **onload="test()"** не отрабатывает (

Comment: @Regent можно, но делать одинаковые ID - это в принципе плохо :)

Comment: @PashaPash так ведь в этом же и суть вопроса: из _плохо_ сделать _хорошо_ :) Бывает ведь ситуации, когда на формирование HTML на сервере повлиять нельзя.

Comment: На сервере такие вещи надо делать!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно воспользоваться селектором `[id="select"]` и методом `.attr()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id="select"]').attr('id', function(i) {
        return 'select' + (i + 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="select"><td>tr1</td></tr>
    <tr id="select"><td>tr2</td></tr>
    <tr id="select"><td>tr3</td></tr>
    <tr id="select"><td>tr4</td></tr>
    <tr id="select"><td>tr5</td></tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Игорь на здоровье. Если ответ вам подходит, не забудьте отметить его как правильный.